# Flutter: Listview is scrolling on iOS but not on Android

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Custom Widget Listview is scrolling properly on iOS devices but not on Andriod devices. I checked on multiple devices, the same result. I'm using the same widget in BottomSheet it works just fine on both platforms. I couldn't figure out what is the issue.
The following is the code:

UI Screen

```
class OnBoardingScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  //
  final _dataAssetController = Get.find<DataAsset>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              image: AssetImage('images/ss.jpg'),
            ),
          ),
          child: SafeArea(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, top: 25.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  ///----------------------   Title
                  Text(
                    'Your',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 30.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Star Sign?',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 45.0,
                      fontFamily: 'FredokaOne',
                      letterSpacing: 2.0,
                      color: _dataAssetController.mainColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 15.0),

                  ///----------------------   Zodiac List
                  ZodiacListWidget(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Listview Widget

```
class ZodiacListWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  //
  final _dataAssetController = Get.find<DataAsset>();

  //
  final _zodiacController = Get.find<ZodiacApiController>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: _dataAssetController.zodiacList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
          return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
            child: Card(
              color: Colors.grey[800],
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
              ),
              child: ListTile(
                title: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
                  child: Text(
                    _dataAssetController.zodiacList[index],
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey[100],
                      fontSize: 25.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                subtitle: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
                  child: Text(
                    _dataAssetController.zodiacDateRangeList[index],
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey[500],
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 20.0,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(
                    _dataAssetController.zodiacSVGList[index],
                    color: _dataAssetController.mainColor,
                  ),
                ),
                trailing: IconButton(
                  icon: GetBuilder<ZodiacApiController>(
                    builder: (_zController) => Icon(
                      Icons.adjust,
                      size: 25.0,
                      color: _dataAssetController.zodiacList[index] ==
                              _zController.zodiacSign
                          ? _dataAssetController.mainColor
                          : Colors.grey[300],
                    ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _zodiacController.changeZodiac(index);
                    _zodiacController.onBoarding != null
                        ? null
                        : Get.defaultDialog(
                            title: '',
                            titleStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 0.0,
                            ),
                            middleText: _zodiacController.zodiacSign!,
                            middleTextStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 30.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                            textConfirm: 'Confirm',
                            confirmTextColor: Colors.white,
                            onConfirm: () {
                              _zodiacController.onBoarding != null
                                  ? null
                                  : _zodiacController.changeOnBoarding();
                              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => HomeScreen(),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                            textCancel: 'Back',
                            cancelTextColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                            onCancel: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                          );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does your list is higher than the height of your Android phone? On Android, ListView don't scroll if they don't have the need to as all the content available is visible to the user... but iOS uses a bouncing animation so, it will always "scroll" even if they don't show more data.

Comment: Why is everything inside a `SingleChildScrollView` with `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics`? Don't know if that is the issue, but it seems a bit weird.

Comment: Yes, Listview is bigger than the screen I guess. Any solutions? @MarianoZorrilla

Comment: Oh, wait... you have a ListView inside a ScrollView?! Don't do that, it's not going to work and app will break out of memory for sure as ScrollView loads everything in memory. You need to use a CustomScrollView and use Slivers.